# Please add a search box on Answerama.com

Tags: feature-request, futurama, search

Most websites nowadays have a search box. Stack Exchange sites encourage you to search whether someone has already asked your question, so it's especially important that they have a search box.

Please add a search box at the top of the [Answerama](http://answerama.com/) page.

Comment: Or at least a note or link somewhere saying "has your question been asked yet? why not search for it?"

Comment: (in the "why not Zoidberg?" voice.)